# How to build a HAMT with multi-index keys

Tags: indexing, trie

By that I mean, forming a [Hash Array Mapped Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie) with 2 or more indexed fields, such as a `User` model by email and location name, or email + username + last logged in + isActive. Basically any arbitrary number of columns of any type of field (boolean, int, string, pretty much).

I am just [learning](https://lampwww.epfl.ch/papers/idealhashtrees.pdf) about [HAMTs](https://github.com/mattbierner/hamt), but don't yet see exactly how they work. I understand how tries and hashtables work though.

My question is how it would look to describe a HAMT that works as a multi-column index.